# DetailView not open when parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing

Downloaded here so [cute parser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser), and decided to move to a newer platform, suffered like everything, but now does not work Detail. That would not be unfounded [here is my project](http://cl.ly/280B04260b3L?_ga=1.128603530.701167339.1426154549). Ie tell me how can I do so that would be when you click on the news, it was revealed a detailed description? I understand the case in a "connection" that in the old project there is a bunch of view - file's owner, in a new project, I was not able to think through how its done only reason for this?

Comment: Maybe it's due to the fact that navigationController is nil, but how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You may display your parsed data into a dynamic table view once the whole data are parsed using the `- (void)feedParserDidFinish:(MWFeedParser *)parser` method (you can add data progressively but the easiest way is waiting the end of the parsing).

Then catch the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` method enclosed into UITableViewDelegate, and perform a segue toward your detail view, passing the selected item as parameter to your detail view controller.

Answer (score 0):

need to change the type Segway with buttons instead of the modal point show
and add to the top of UINavigationController storyboard